# How do I plot a graph using three columns, two as the x and y axis and the last one as the colour?

Tags: python, matplotlib, colors

[image]

My code didn't work. pandas as pd and matplotlib.pyplot as plt were preloaded.

> import plotly.express as px
> # Set the figure style and initalize a new figure
> plt.style.use('fivethirtyeight')
> fig = plt.figure(figsize=(12,8))
>
> ```
> # Create a scatter plot of duration versus release_year 
> a = netflix_movies_col_subset["release_year"] 
> b = netflix_movies_col_subset["duration"] 
> c = colors 
> data1 = {"Release year": a, "Duration": b, "Rating": c} 
> df1 = pd.DataFrame(data1) 
> print(df1) 
> px.scatter(df1, x = "Release year", y = "Duration", color = "Rating")
>
> # Create a title and axis labels 
> plt.title("Movie duration by year of release") 
> plt.xlabel("Release year") 
> plt.ylabel("Duration (min)")
>
> # Show the plot 
> plt.show()
> ```

I am unsure why this didn't work on Anaconda:

> ```
> # Set the figure style and initialize a new figure
> plt.style.use('fivethirtyeight')
> fig = plt.figure(figsize=(12,8))
>
> # Create a scatter plot of duration versus release_year
> plt.scatter(netflix_movies_col_subset["release_year"],netflix_movies_col_subset["duration"])
>
> # Create a title and axis labels
> plt.title("Movie duration by year of release")
> plt.xlabel("Release year")
> plt.ylabel("Duration (min)")
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Update code this way and you should be able to see the charts (minus the dummy data)... Also, not sure if you really need to move from netflix_movie_col_subset to df to df1, etc.

```
import plotly.express as px # Set the figure style and initalize a new figure plt.style.use('fivethirtyeight') fig = plt.figure(figsize=(12,8))

data = {'release_year': [2020, 2021, 1993, 2021, 2021, 2015, 2007, 2009, 2006, 2015],
        'duration':[90, 91, 125, 104, 127, 96, 158, 88, 88, 111], 
        'Rating': ['black', 'red', 'blue', 'blue', 'black', 'black', 'blue', 'blue', 'black', 'black']}

netflix_movies_col_subset=pd.DataFrame(data)

# Create a scatter plot of duration versus release_year 
a = netflix_movies_col_subset["release_year"] 
b = netflix_movies_col_subset["duration"] 
c =  netflix_movies_col_subset["Rating"] 
data1 = {"Release year": a, "Duration": b, "Rating": c} 
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data1) 
print(df1) 
plt = px.scatter(df1, x = "Release year", y = "Duration", color = "Rating", 
                labels={"Release year": "Release year", # Not really required
                        "Duration": "Duration (min)",}, 
                )

plt.update_layout(title_text='Movie duration by year of release', title_x=0.5)                 

# Show the plot 
plt.show()
```

**Output**

[image: Plotly express image]